# Выполняется фильтр при перезагрузке страницы Django. Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, django-filter

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть файл с фильтром(`liked.py`). Код фильтра:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def liked(obj):
   obj.like_count += 1
   obj.save()
   print("liked", obj.like_count)
```

Фильтр я использую в функции javascript:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.liked", function liked(){
        {{ article|liked }}
  });
```

Так вот, при перезагрузке страницы со скриптом фильтр в like_count добавляет 1, а когда я вызываю javascript функцию фильтр молчит. А должно быть наоборот!
Сразу скажу, что дело не в Vk.observer, он работает корректно. Ошибок django никаких не показывает.
В интернете ничего про это не нашел, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: фильтр работает в момент рендеринга страницы на сервере (т.е. когда клиент присылает запрос и сервер генерирует html). На выходе получается некий текст, который в вашем случае вставляется в страницу. При вызове javascript функции `liked` питон код фильтра не вызывается, вместо этого выполняется тело функции `liked`, а в теле - тот текст, который фильтр сгенерировал раньше, и этот текст трактуется как javascript код и браузер пробует его выполнять.

Comment: Большое спасибо, что объяснили. Получается, что python код как бы переводится в javascript код, но почему он тогда выполняется при рендеринге? Я его нигде не вызывал

Comment: Вот нашел похожий ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952156/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-to-django-custom-filter. Получается, во время рендеринга django не замечает javascript и просто выполняет фильтр. Проблему вроде разобрали, но как ее решить?

Comment: `{{ article|liked }}` - когда вы такое написали в шаблоне, то этим вы вызвали фильтр `liked` с аргументом `article`. Чтоб понять, как решить проблему, нужно понять в чем ваша задача. При нажатии на кнопку like пользователем вы хотите в БД увеличивать счетчик?  Если так, то фильтр тут вообще ни к месту. Вам нужно создать отдельную view в django и привязать ее к какому-то url-у, в котором будет id статьи. При выполнении запроса на этот url, нужно брать статью из БД и увеличивать счетчик. А в js функции нужно делать запрос на сервер с этим url и передавать в нем id статьи.

Comment: хм... Я подумал над вашим предложением. Получается, что просто будет временная переадресация пользователя. Но тогда, если у пользователя слабый интернет, он сможет отследить сам url адрес и искусственно исправлять данные в БД. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то это исправить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы называете "временной переадресацией". Далее тоже не уверен, что понимаю. Если речь о том, как запретить пользователю накручивать количество лайков, т.е. чтоб он не мог два раза (или больше) увеличить счетчик, то тут можно генерировать уникальное случайное значение при создании страницы и его включать в ссылку в качестве параметра. Когда запрос приходит на сервер, нужно проверять, что это случайное значение, еще не использовалось и только тогда делать изменения значения. Если же использовалось, то игнорировать. Таким образом каждую ссылку можно будет использовать 1 раз

Comment: Большое Спасибо, я как раз это и хотел сделать. Идея хорошая, но есть недостатки. Если мы просто генерируем случайное число и проверяем, что оно не использовалось, то тогда можно столкнутся с следующими проблемами:
1. Пользователь все равно накручивать лайки, он просто может вручную писать случайное число
2. Допустим, я решил взять 8-значные числа. Что будет с БД через год? Там будет хранится огромное количество больших чисел. Поэтому проверка адреса на присутствие в БД будет долгой

Comment: Я предлагаю генерировать случайное число и записывать его в отдельный столбец БД. Потом отдавать модельку и уже брать случайное число из модельки.

Comment: Идея была в том, чтоб сохранять сгенерирванное значение в БД и потом проверять. И оно должно быть большим, больше чем 8 знаков. Тут есть несколько ньюансов, плюс насколько такое решение применимо зависит от некоторых условий, тут это все обсуждать неудобно. Лучше задать отдельный вопрос и так уже описать задачу и можно будет уточнить недостающие детали.

Comment: Спасибо большое, мне уже все понятно. Я вижу, вы в этом деле разбираетесь. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, стоит ли менять это случайное число при открытии статьи для безопасности.